# Android Studio 4.0 incompativel Flutter Plugin

Tags: android-studio, flutter

O Android Studio alcançou a versão 4.0, no entanto antes de fazer o update avisa que o plugin do flutter e do dart são incompatíveis com a nova versão do Android Studio. Alguém já tentou alguma solução, ou simplesmente não fizeram o update? Obrigado.

Comment: A resposta do Rafael está correta, eu atualizei tudo e continua compilando meus projetos sem problemas.

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, funcionou...

Comment: Da um positivo para na resposta dele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem issues ([#4136](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4136) e [#4166](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/4166)) no repositório do Flutter sobre o assunto.

Aparentemente, a mensagem `Plugins incompatibe with the new build found` exibida pelo Android Studio está defasada, sendo um "falso aviso". Atualize a IDE e, em seguida, os plugins, e tudo funcionará corretamente.